# MUI ClickAwayListener closing the modal itself when clicked (React.Js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, frontend

The required functionality for modal is that when clicked on the 'More' button, it should be visible and when either the More button or any other part of the screen is clicked (excluding the modal itself), the modal should be closed. I have tried various ways starting from https://usehooks-typescript.com/react-hook/use-on-click-outside & MUI's `ClickAwayListener`.

```
<ClickAwayListener
  onClickAway={handleClickAway}
>
  <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
    <button
      onClick={(e: any) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
      }}
    >
      More
    </button>
    <Modal
      visible={modalVisible}
      id="btn-container"
    >
        {dummy.map((str: string) => {
          return <span>{str}</span>;
        })}
    </Modal>
  </div>
</ClickAwayListener>
```

```
const handleClickAway = (e: any) => {
    if (e.target.localName === 'body') {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

    setModalVisible(false);
  };
```

```
const Modal = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: -200px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 25px;
  z-index: 8;
  visibility: ${({ visible }) => (visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden')};
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 250px;
  max-height: 320px;
  overflow-y: auto;
`;
```

Basically, the `ClickAwayListener` is not able to detect it's child component and is closing the modal even when I click inside the modal which should not be the functionality.

'Modal' component used here isn't a materialui component, it's a styled component that I built myself

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `onBackdropClick` in `Modal` instead of `onClickAway`, `onBackdropClick` fires when you clicks outside the `Modal`

```
<Modal onBackdropClick={() => setOpen(false)}
```

2. Use `onClose` in `Modal` instead of `onBackdropClick`, `onClose` fires when the `Modal` want to close itself

```
<Modal onClose={(_, reason) => reason === 'backdropClick' && setOpen(false)}
```

3. Use [`Dialog`](https://mui.com/components/dialogs/#main-content) instead of `Modal`. `Dialog` is the component containing the `Modal` with good default styles out-of-the-box while `Modal` is its ugly cousin used for low level customization.

```
<Dialog onClose={(_, reason) => reason === 'backdropClick' && setOpen(false)}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but Modal isn't a material ui component, it is a very basic styled component that I built myself. Can you please update your answer accordingly?

Comment: @HardikAswal Why don't use MUI component? I'll update my answer then.

Comment: @HardikAswal Also please put your modal definition code in your question.

Comment: I have shared the modal code. I dont want to use mui dialog for a number of reasons and would rather stick with this modal that I built myself.

Comment: My only question being, why is the ClickAwayListener not able to detect it's own child component?

Comment: @HardikAswal replace `setTagsModalVisible` in your `handleClickAway` with `setModalVisible` I suppose? [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicmodal-material-demo-forked-h3e24?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: That's a mistake on my part while changing the code for posting the question. Made change in the code

Comment: @HardikAswal My point is, it works fine in the codesandbox

Comment: Exactly. I even have the same html elements inside the ClickAwayListener as the example from mui. Still it's unable to detect its child component

Comment: @HardikAswal I can only help you if I can reproduce the problem in the codesandbox, can you fork my codesandbox and add all of your relevant code?